# Spring Batch persist data from step1 to step2

Tags: spring-batch

I have thoroughly searched the Spring docs and supporting sites, but have not found and answer to this inquiry; if I want to access and store some values in the ExecutionContext, do I have to write custom databaseItemReader and ItemWriter's that implement the ItemStream or can I use the "out-of-the-box" readers and writers and edit the beans in the spring-batch-context.xml file to do this? Any code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd">

```
<import resource="classpath:context-datasource.xml" />

<!-- JobRepository and JobLauncher are configuration/setup classes -->
<bean id="jobRepository"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean" />

<bean id="jobLauncher"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
</bean>


<!-- ItemReader which reads from database and returns the row mapped by 
    rowMapper -->
<bean id="databaseItemReader"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader">

    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

    <property name="sql"
        value="SELECT PartnerID, ftpUserName, ftpPassword, ftpPath, jobRunTime, jobFrequency FROM tblRosterJobParams" />

    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean class="com.explorelearning.batch.ParamResultRowMapper" />
    </property>

</bean>


<!-- This was supposed to change to a SavingItemWriter that persists these values to the Step ExecutionContext -->
<bean id="flatFileItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter"
    scope="step">

    <property name="resource" value="file:csv/ParamResult.txt" />

    <property name="lineAggregator">

        <!--An Aggregator which converts an object into delimited list of strings -->
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">

            <property name="delimiter" value="," />

            <property name="fieldExtractor">

                <!-- Extractor which returns the value of beans property through reflection -->
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
                    <property name="names" value="PartnerID" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Optional JobExecutionListener to perform business logic before and after the job -->
<bean id="jobListener" class="com.explorelearning.batch.RosterBatchJobListener" />

<!-- Optional StepExecutionListener to perform business logic before and after the job -->
<bean id="stepExecutionListener" class="com.explorelearning.batch.ParamResultStepExecutionListener" />

<!-- Optional ItemProcessor to perform business logic/filtering on the input records -->
<bean id="itemProcessor" class="com.explorelearning.batch.ParamResultItemProcessor" />

<!-- Step will need a transaction manager -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

<!-- Actual Job -->
<batch:job-repository id="jobRepository"  data-source="dataSource" table-prefix="BATCH_"
    transaction-manager="transactionManager" isolation-level-for-create="SERIALIZABLE" />
<batch:job id="RosterBatchJob" job-repository="jobRepository">
 <batch:step id="readParams" >
    <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager" allow-start-if-complete="true">
        <batch:chunk reader="databaseItemReader"  writer="flatFileItemWriter"
            processor="itemProcessor" commit-interval="10" />
    </batch:tasklet>
 </batch:step>
 <!--<batch:step id="grabCSVs" next="validateCSVs">

 </batch:step>
 <batch:step id="validateCSVs" next="filterRecords">

 </step>
 <batch:step id="filterRecords" next="determineActions">

 </batch:step>
  <batch:step id="determineActions" next="executeActions">

 </batch:step>
  <batch:step id="executeActions" next="">

 </batch:step>  -->

</batch:job>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated now that the question has more detail...**

Okay, the way I'm reading your context file, you need to:

1. Get some FTP login info from the Database
2. Download some CSV files
3. Validate the files (file-level? or just record-level validation?)
4. Filter out some garbage records
5. Determine some "actions"
6. Execute some "actions"

The best way to accomplish this (in my opinion) is to create the following steps:

1. Step 1: A simple `Tasklet` that queries the database for FTP login info and then downloads the CSV files to a local folder
2. Step 2: Partitioned step that creates one partition per CSV in the folder

   1. Each partition will have a reader (`FlatFileItemReader`) that reads out records.
   2. Records will then go to an `ItemProcessor` that returns `null` if the record is garbage.
   3. Valid items will be written to some DB staging table for further action
   4. Optionally you can use a `ClassifierItemWriter` to do something w/ the junk records
3. Step 3: The next step reads the valid data in the staging table and does "Actions"
4. Step 4: Maybe another step to do something with the junk records

Comment: Thanks Dean! I'll give it a shot and let you know how it turned out!

Comment: Dean,It just so happens that I already had a listener built so I added the suggested listgener to my step but I'm getting this error:

Comment: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'listeners'. One of '{"http://
 www.springframework.org/schema/batch":transaction-attributes, "http://
 www.springframework.org/schema/batch":no-rollback-exception-classes, "http://
 www.springframework.org/schema/batch":listeners, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/
 beans":bean, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":ref}' is expected.

Comment: Do I need to put the String "www.springframework.org/schema/beans" in front of the "ref" attribute?

Comment: <batch:step id="readParams" >
  <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager" >
   <batch:chunk reader="databaseItemReader"  writer="flatFileItemWriter"
    processor="itemProcessor" commit-interval="10" />
   <batch:listeners>
                  <batch:listener ref="ParamResultStepExecutionListener"/>
         </batch:listeners>
  </batch:tasklet>
  </batch:step>

Comment: After further review, this error indicates a missing tag.

Comment: Yep, just needed to close the <tasklet> tag :)

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, please just mark this answer as "Accepted"

Comment: Roger that, ... Thanks!

Comment: Dean, I have tried this without success, the Execution Context is not picking up any value so it fails when the second step tries to initialize with a a null value that should be an int.

Comment: Just to clarify, I have successfully used a databaseItemReader to grab some values from a table and I am trying to use those values in the next step. so instead of passing a random String to the Execution context I am actually trying to pass the values I grabbed from the database to the Execution Context.

Comment: You may persist small bits of data to the Job's ExecutionContext (which will be shared between steps). You do NOT want to use that heavily. Can you combine the steps somehow? Unfortunately, without more info about your job I can't give a ton more detail. Can you augment your original Question with the nature of the data being passed from Step 1 to 2 and the nature of the data being read in Step 2?

Comment: Yes, I have databaseItemReader that has grabbed the following values from a table in the database:

Comment: <bean id="databaseItemReader"
  class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader">

  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

  <property name="sql"
   value="SELECT PartnerID, ftpUserName, ftpPassword, ftpPath, jobRunTime, jobFrequency FROM tblRosterJobParams" />

  <property name="rowMapper">
   <bean class="com.explorelearning.batch.ParamResultRowMapper" />
  </property>

Comment: I want to take and put three of those values (PartnerID, ftpUserName, and ftpPassword) in the Execution context so that the next step can log into the FTP server with them.

Comment: I know that the databaseItemReader is grabbing the values because I can  write them to the console

Comment: As I suspected, you'll want to use a different pattern here and combine the 2 steps into 1. It's hard to write code in the comments, so can you please edit your original question at the top of the page with your current Context file?

Once I see that, I can help you refactor it to either use a `Tasklet` or implement `ItemStream` (or `StepExecutionListener`) to effectively combine these 2 steps into 1.

Comment: Dean, Thanks for taking a look. Yes, that is exactly what I am trying to do. I have the databaseItemReader getting the ftp login information. Now I need to use that data to log in to the FTP server. How do I pass that data to the second step using execution context?

Comment: Again, you would NOT do this with 2 steps. Instead, make Step 1 be a `Tasklet` which in the `execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext)` method first does a quick DB lookup for the credentials and then uses those credentials to open an FTP session and download the files. This will eliminate the need to "pass information between steps". Again, using a single `Tasklet` here makes far more sense to me than two `reader-writer` steps.